# character tables for groups of order $pq^2$

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory, characters

What is the character table for groups or order $pq^2$?  The [classification of order $pq^2$ groups](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/57938/application-of-the-sylow-theorems-to-groups-of-order-p2q) has already been discussed in relation to [Sylow theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylow_theorems).

For the Abelian groups, $\mathbb{Z}_p \oplus \mathbb{Z}_{q^2}$ and $\mathbb{Z}_p \oplus \mathbb{Z}_q \oplus \mathbb{Z}_q$, all the irreducible representations are 1-dimensional.

According to some [group theory lecture notes](http://www.math.rochester.edu/people/faculty/jonpak/N7.pdf) I found online (bottom of page 8), there is only one other group when $q \not\equiv 1 (\mod p)$ and two when $q \equiv 1 (\mod p)$.   I am asking for  the character table in any or all of these cases.

Comment: Try looking at the "method of little groups" as explained in Serre's book.  This gives a way of calculating all irreps of any group that has a large normal abelian subgroup as certain induced representations.

Comment: There are more groups of order pqq than you indicate.  For instance, there are 8 groups of order 5887 up to isomorphism, not just four.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any group of order $pq^2$ is a semidirect product by an abelian group. Indeed, by Sylow theory either the Sylow $p$-subgroup or the Sylow $q$-subgroup is normal. The [Schur-Zassenhaus theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur-Zassenhaus_theorem) says that if a normal subgroup has order coprime to its index, then it has a complement.

To classify all irreducible character of semidirect products by abelian groups is a very nice exercise in character theory. See [another answer of mine](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/38571/classifying-the-irreducible-representations-of-mathbbz-p-mathbbz-rtimes-ma/38589#38589) for details. This is from Serre's representation theory book Part II, Section 8.2.