# There are $5$ groups of order $12$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, alternative-proof

I have been looking for a short proof of the problem

> There are exactly five groups of order 12: three non-abelian and two abelian.

I know the proof of the statement, but I want to know if there is a short proof without considering all the possible relations of each element of the group with others.

**EDIT:** To let a brief explanation of the proof I know about this problem, what I did was consider an element $y$ of order $3$ and an element $x$ of order $4$, then consider the set generated by them:
$$\{e,x,x^2,x^3,y,yx,yx^2,yx^3,y^2,y^2x,y^2x^2,y^2x^3\}$$

Then what I did was relate them with the elements of structure $y^mx^t$, that is reduced considering that some elements could not be equal considering their orders or the elements that are eliminated between them.

Comment: Yes, corrected.

Comment: Well, how about you letting us know the proof of the statement you know; we can't give you a "short(er)  proof" without knowing that.

Comment: @amWhy I let the way of my proof, but considering that is very large, I only added the parts that are useful to understand it.

Comment: How you prove that they're the only ones? For the abelian case is very easy. But for the non abelian, it isn't. In fact you're missing $D_{12}$ (or $D_6$ depending of the author)

Comment: How do you know there is an element $x$ of order 4 in the group? (You don't, since sometimes there isn't.)

Comment: Actually, two abelian and three nonabelian.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well..the abelian ones are all products of appropriate cyclic groups; those aren't too tough to enumerate.

For non-abelian, the Sylow theorems tell you a lot about groups of order $p^2 q$, where $p$ and $q$ are prime: basically they're all semi-direct products, and there just aren't too many homomorphisms to use in forming the product, so it's pretty straightforward. If you don't know the Sylow theorems or semi-direct products...it's tougher.

Look especially at Dylan Moreland's answer to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/57938/application-of-the-sylow-theorems-to-groups-of-order-p2q) question.

Comment: Damn, you're right. The semidirect product was what I was looking for the non-abelian case.

Comment: Yes, with this is very clear considering the semidirect products. Considering that I finished in less than an hour, yes, is very short.